SQLAlchemy on Azure Function - Login TimeOut Expired
I have a Fast API app running on an Azure Function on a consumption plan. This is connecting to a SQL Azure database using SQLAlchemy. If I try to make a request to the API after a long idle period the first request always fails with an OperationError : Login TimeOut Expired. Subsequent requests work as normal & I get data.
The get_db call is used as a Dependency in Fast API. I have tried to attempt retries but it still doesnt seem to work. Any ideas would be appreciated
RETRIES = 3
DELAY = 5  # delay in seconds

DATABASE_URL = ("mssql+pyodbc://username:MyPassword@sql-servername.database.windows.net"
                 "/sqldb-mydatabase"
                 "?driver=ODBC+Driver+18+for+SQL+Server"
                 "&Encrypt=yes"
                 "&TrustServerCertificate=no"
                 "&ConnectionTimeout=30")

engine = create_engine(
    DATABASE_URL,
    pool_size=10,    # Number of connections to maintain in the pool
    max_overflow=20,  # Additional connections that can be created beyond the pool_size
    pool_timeout=30,  # Maximum time in seconds to wait for a connection
    pool_recycle=1800,  # Recycle connections after this many seconds
    pool_pre_ping=True,  # Ensures connections are tested before use
    # Additional Azure-specific connection parameters
    connect_args={
        'connect_timeout': 30,# Max time in seconds to establish a connection 
        'login_timeout': 30,
    }
)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

# base class for all ORM models in SQLAlchemy which is used to set up metadata
# for mapping models to database tables.
Base = declarative_base()


def get_db():
    '''Get's a database instance for the session & ensure it's properly closed'''

    for attempt in range(RETRIES):
        try:
            db = SessionLocal()
            # Test the connection by executing a simple query
            data = db.execute(text('SELECT 1'))
            logging.info("Able to fetch a user after making a connection")
            yield db
            break
        except (OperationalError, DBAPIError) as oe:
            logging.error("Database connection failed: %s", oe)

            if attempt < RETRIES - 1:

                logging.info("Retry attempt (%d) for connecting to the database...",
                             (attempt + 1)/RETRIES)

                time.sleep(DELAY)

            else:
                logging.critical(
                    "Database connection failed after (%d) attempts.", RETRIES)
                raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
                                    detail="Database connection failed, please try again later.") from e
        finally:
            if db:
                
                db.close()


SOLVED
Removed the if check before the db.execute and deployed the code again & it is working now. Maybe the function didn't get reset or was not deployed correctly that time.
There is a delay on accessing the API after a long idle time but it doesnt error now and returns a proper response. Subsequent calls seem to be working too

Try using Always On Option which prevents function from cold start

This happens because in Function App, after some time the function app becomes idle and it takes cold start always after break, You should warmup the connection string so that the function warms and one can avoid the cold start.
So, you can use timer trigger that does not do any thing or restart the connection recurringly.
Or use the App Service Plan for the function app, so that you use use Always On Option On which keeps the function warm:

For further information please refer SO-Thread's answer.

I am using a consumption plan and can't see an "Always On" option. Can I not use python code to handle this and add a delay or wait for warm up

Only in App service plan you can get it. I suggest you to either use warming up codes or try using app service plan.
